# How to query Umbraco's 7.X page setting (Grid Layout) to create a menu?

Tags: umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco 7.3.3 to create a home page with a verical parallax scroll menu. My approach is to create a Editor/View for each specific section and use a setting (from Grid Layout property editor) to render the ID that I'll use as anchor for my main navigation.

I've also tried to create the sections as Child Documents but it's lacks the ability to freely reorder the sections.

Is the first option the best approach to create a Grid Layout with Parallax Scroll navigation? Can someone point a different/better way to create a "scroll down" navigation menu?

The backbone is OK but I don't know how to query CurrentPage's settings under MainNavigation.cshtml Partial (I'm using Fanoe Starter Kit).

How can I query by a specific CurrentPage's setting?

I'm expecting something like:

```
// first try (Does NOT work)
CurrentPage.GetProperty("content").Where(s => s.some lambda expression)

//another tried option based on GetGridHtml method (Does NOT work)
CurrentPage.GetGrid("content")...
```

Here is the setting configuration for each row that should have a navigation item in menu:

```
  [{
    "label": "Section Name",
    "description": "Type the section name",
    "key": "id",
    "view": "textstring",
    "applyTo": "row"
  }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an extra research and I found ([here](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/61071-Accessing-the-grid-layout-content-programmatically) and [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/Grid-Layout/Grid-Layout-Best-Practices)) that there is no API that handles the serialized JSON stored by the Grid Layout Editor.

> **Limitations** With the above usage scenarios in mind, consider the grids limitations. First of all, all content entered into the grid is stored as a single property value on the content node, as a big JSON object. This means that as soon as the values are stored in the database, there is no managed api to drill into the grid content and target specific cell content - so a grid layout is not a recommended storage of reusable content - it simply wasn't designed for this scenario. If you wish to reuse content in multiple pages, it is still recommended that you store these pieces of content as separate content nodes, so they can be stored, cached and queried as usual.